# Why are non-static methods allowed in applets?

Tags: java, static-methods, appletviewer

I've noted that adding a non-static method to the class containing the main method in a java-application and then calling it from within the main-method, results in a compilation error. This I can understand, since this class is never instantiated.

However, adding a non-static method to an Applet-class and calling it from within, say, the paint method works fine. Why is this? Is the applet-class somehow instantiated by appletviewer, or is there another explanation as to why the former isn't allowed while the latter is?

Comment: Did you notice [`paint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics)) is not a static method? ;)

Comment: I did actually, and yes, I see your point :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is the applet-class somehow instantiated by appletviewer

Absolutely. See the ["Life Cycle of an Applet"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/lifeCycle.html) section of the [Applets tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html). In particular:

> As a result of the applet being loaded, you should see the text "initializing... starting...". When an applet is loaded, here's what happens:
>
> - An instance of the applet's controlling class (an Applet subclass) is created.
> - The applet initializes itself.
> - The applet starts running.